# Can someone in a github org read .github files even when the repository is marked private?

Tags: github

I'm part of a large organisation that has its own internal github and many disparate teams, some with private repositories containing sensitive information. We've been told to add metadata json files inside a .github folder to all of our repos. I am wondering if there is any point to add them into a private repository considering that whatever is reading these files won't not have read access?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, access to a repository is controlled on a per-repository basis, and someone who has access to read a repository has access to all of it (that is, there is no partial read access).  However, it's possible for an organization admin, or, on GitHub Enterprise Server, a server admin, to grant privileges to repositories, even if the repository admins don't grant that access.

That, for example, can be used to grant bots permission to read data, such as for a service catalog or other information, or to allow repositories to be deployed using standard tooling.  A GitHub App can also be used for this purpose, and since it could be authorized for the entire organization, it could have access to all of the repositories.  Thus, it is possible that some service *will* have access to these repositories.